# Print $base_url

Tags: theming, 8, uri

How can I print `$base_url` in a template?

Comment: FWIW, you almost never need to reference the base_url in Drupal 8 directly, especially in template files.  In nearly all cases, there are better options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$base_url` is not available to template files, but you can easily add it to every template file by implementing [`hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter/8.2.x) in a theme or a module.

```
function mytheme_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables) {
  $variables['base_url'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'];
}
```

Then, in your template file, you just print its value with the following code.

```
{{ base_url }}
```

Comment: that is a very neat hook! I didn't know about it before. Adding for the reference - [hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter/8.2.x)

Answer (score 1):

After a little research. You can't do that. You have to use preprocess functions, controllers, or alter hooks to provide $base_url later on in your twig template file.